# Create Class at Runtime, File not Found Exception

Tags: c#, class, .net-assembly

im having a Problem creating a Class at runtime. Everytime i debug the code below i get the following error message at `var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("test.DummyHelloWorldHandler");`
 Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\1ivc3qic.dll' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

the Name of the *.dll file differs everytime i debug the programm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;


namespace DynamicNS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Collections.dll");
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, GetCode());
            var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("test.DummyHelloWorldHandler");
            var method = cls.GetMethod("Received", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            object[] parms = { "Hallo Welt" };
            method.Invoke(null, parms);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string[] GetCode()
        {
            return new string[]
            {
                @"using System.Collections;
                namespace test
                {
                    public class DummyHelloWorldHandler 
                    {
                        protected internal Queue _queue;  
                        public void Received(string message) 
                        {
                            lock (_queue) 
                            { 
                                _queue.Enqueue(message); 
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine('Enqueued');
                        } 
                        public DummyHelloWorldHandler() 
                        {
                            _queue = new Queue(); 
                        } 
                    }
                }"
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You use `BindingFlags.Static`, but `Received` is not static.

Comment: I am receiving this same issue but there are no errors in my result.Errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code returned by `GetCode` does not compile because of the wrong quotes.
You can check that by iterating over the `Errors` property of your `CompilerResults`.

You have to remove this line:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Collections.dll");
```

and change the `GetCode()` method like this:

```
private static string[] GetCode()
{
  return new string[]
        {
          @"using System;
            using System.Collections;
            namespace test
            {
                public class DummyHelloWorldHandler 
                {
                    protected internal Queue _queue;  

                    public void Received(string message) 
                    {
                        lock (_queue) 
                        { 
                            _queue.Enqueue(message); 
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(""Enqueued"");
                    } 
                    public DummyHelloWorldHandler() 
                    {
                        _queue = new Queue(); 
                    } 
                }
            }"
        };
}
```

Comment: @Liviu How can `Console.WriteLine('Enqueued')` possibly compile?

Comment: @Matthew Watson because of the quotes (")

Comment: @Wolfgang Ziegler Because the other two already said it doesn't compile when the build is ok.

Comment: @Liviu We are talking about the code in quotes that he's trying to dynamically compile. That's where the problem is. We're *not* talking about the program that is dynamically compiling the code. Can you see the difference?

Comment: @Matthew Watson Ooops, now I understand, how can I repair it ?

Comment: Phew, glad we got that straight. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your code could actually be compiled? You seem to be missing a semicolon after your using statement.

Check the `Errors` property of your results, it contains the errors that were encountered while compiling your source.

Comment: So what is in the Errors property?

Comment: @nvoigt Please edit your answer so I can undo my downvote, sorry !

Answer (score 1):

```
 @"using System.Collection
```

Should probably be

```
 @"using System.Collections;
```

Also: `Console.WirteLine()`? Hmmm. Perhaps you should paste that entire GetCode() string into a test program, make it compile, and then paste it back into your original project.

After your edits, this still won't compile:

```
Console.WriteLine('Enqueued');
```

It's got single quotes instead of double quotes around the string.

Comment: It builds ok, you are missing the quotes (")

Comment: @gangfish You can't have pasted the code into another project and built it there, otherwise you'll have seen that `Console.WriteLine('Enqueued');` won't compile because `'Enqueued'` should be `"Enqueued"` (double quotes, not single quotes). There may be other problems, hence why I think you should paste and compile first.

Comment: @Liviu The code can't possibly compile if it has `Console.WriteLine('Enqueued');` in it, now can it? I'm talking about the code that's being dynamically compiled, *not* the code that's dynamically compiling it!

Comment: @Matthew You're right, it's my mistake, sorry, I reverted the downvote.